# Flutter facebook share dialog can't open on android 10 or high version device

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

i use social_share_plugin to share link on facebook, when i test the app on android 8 device, it's run normal. But when i test on android 10 device, that can't open facebook share dialog.

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
      <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
   </queries>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
           android:value="@string/app_name"/>

       <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
           android:configChanges=
               "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
           android:label="@string/app_name" />

       <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1051111111111"
           android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
           android:exported="true"/>
```

```
await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebookLink(quote: share.shareDescription, url: share.shareUrl);
```